# Modify Name in Wrapper class with sObject type

Tags: apex, lightning, controller, variable-names

I am using code that someone else worked on. From the code, I can tell it is smart enough to recognize that the record it is processing is the current record for the lightning component. How can I then modify the name to explicitly say that for my users?

`if(so.get('id') == currentRecordId` seems to be the key part. `so.get('name')` also seems to work. How can I change the value in `so.get('name')`?

This is the apex controller:

```
//Run query and store results
    List<sObject> queryOutput = new List<sObject>();        
    queryOutput = database.query(finalQueryString);        

    //Loop through the values
    Integer level = 0;
    for(sObject so: queryOutput){
        HierarchyData ss = new HierarchyData();
        if(so.get('id') == currentRecordId /*|| level == 0*/){
            ss.expanded = true;
            //This next line is where I am trying to modify the name.
            so.put(so.get('name'), so.get('name')+': Current Record');
        }else{
            ss.expanded = false;
        }
        ss.rec = so;
        returnValue.add(ss);
        level++;
    }

    //return values to the component
    system.debug('**********returnValue:'+returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}

//Wrapper class
public class HierarchyData{
    @AuraEnabled
    public sObject rec{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public boolean expanded{get;set;}
    public HierarchyData(){
        expanded = false;
    }
}
```

The top part of the code is just defining the variable finalQueryString, which works as expected.

Comment: What happens when you do this? Not all sObjects have mutable Name fields, and I'm not sure this is the optimal solution for your objective.

Comment: I am using this on custom objects that all have name fields. I thought all objects in SF have the name and id field? @battery.cord had the solution as putting just `so.put('Name', 'Some Value');` and that works. What do you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing is the best way to even do what you're doing. It appears that you're expanding/collapsing elements in a tree or table using server-side code. This should be done client-side. It would also help alleviate the problem with trying to set the name, which may not be writable in all cases in Apex Code. Further, I'd generally advise just creating a variable in your wrapper to show the modified text. This is all conjecture based on what I can see, but I suspect you need some refactoring.

Comment: @sfdcfox this is all used to create a lightning:tree. This data is then run through client side stuff too, and it seems to use 'expanded' as a flag. I tried to solve this first client side, but I'd be lying if I said I understood exactly what all is going on. Simply put, I don't have any other way to dynamically create the tree structure I need, and I lack the skills to write it myself.

Comment: @Chance I have an old-school (pre-`lightning:tree`) tree demo you can look at [here](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/32bd056260cf4850ba15bc5641b6c42f). I dunno if it'll help, but there you go.

Comment: OK, that helps a bit. Essentially the code I have is doing something similar. Question though: what does `users[undefined]` mean? I have no idea what undefined means. The code I am using is rough, but at least dynamic. It comes from here: http://www.sfdcstuff.com/2017/10/lightning-tree-generic-lightning.html#comment-form